# SVN Batch file output linebreaks and formatting

Tags: powershell, batch-file, svn, slack-api

I am creating a simple 'post-commit' svn batch script, which will run when a member of our development team commits a build. This batch file sends off the resulting output to a slack service which spits it out to our team channel.

This all works without any problems, but I'd like to put in some bespoke formatting such as new lines and maybe bold text. It's a bit hard to read at present. Being able to break to a new line is the main thing that I'm after.  I've done a lot of searching, but can't seem to find the correct answer.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Here's the contents of  my script currently:

```
set one=%1
set rev=%2
set changes=svnlook changed %one% -r %rev%
set whatchanged=nothing


for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%changes%') do ( set whatchanged=%%a )


for /f "delims=-" %%i in ('%rev%') do (
SET rev=%%i
)


for /f "delims=" %%g in ('svnlook log %one% -r %rev%') do (
 SET comlog=%%g
)

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('svnlook author %one% -r %rev%') do (
 SET "author=%%i"
)

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('svnlook changed %one% -r %rev%') do (
 SET changed=%%i
)


powershell -Command "& Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'our URL with a unique token goes here' -Method Post -Body (ConvertTo-Json @{text='%author% %rev% %one% %comlog% %whatchanged%'})"


REM  All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

The output currently looks like this:

> liam.mcdonald 171 D:\Repositories\company

Here is another one:

> U   Test/New Text Document.txt

Comment: Is this a return of Powershell command?

Comment: To be clear, is the output you show from Slack?

Comment: Why are you running a PowerShell command from a batch script instead of writing the whole script in PowerShell?

Comment: ... or in Batch file?

Comment: You may have a hard time implementing `Invoke-RestMethod` in plain batch (without third-party tools).

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.

So the round trip looks something like this:

-> Team member commits a build.
-> Batch file executes -> sending output to webhook
-> Webhook posts to slack chat channel

This is implemented and working correctly, I'd just like to format the output in a more efficient way.